# "RTextTools" create_matrix got an error

Tags: r, classification, text-mining

I was running RTextTools package to build a text classification model.

And when I prepare the prediction dataset and tried to transform it in to matrix. I got error as:

```
Error in if (attr(weighting, "Acronym") == "tf-idf") weight <- 1e-09 : 
  argument is of length zero
```

My code is as below:

```
table<-read.csv("traintest.csv",header = TRUE)
dtMatrix <- create_matrix(table["COMMENTS"])
container <- create_container(dtMatrix, 
                              table$LIKELIHOOD_TO_RECOMMEND, 
                              trainSize=1:5000,testSize=5001:10000, 
                              virgin=FALSE)
model <- train_model(container, "SVM", kernel="linear", cost=1)

predictionData<-read.csv("rest.csv",header = TRUE)
**predMatrix <- create_matrix(predictionData["COMMENTS"],originalMatrix=dtMatrix)**
Error in if (attr(weighting, "Acronym") == "tf-idf") weight <- 1e-09 : 
      argument is of length zero
```

The error was given by the last code (bold)
I tried search on google but didn't see one clear solution.

Thanks

Comment: The usual method for building items to test is with `head`. Once you have a reproducible example, the preferred method is to use `dput` to delive an unambiguous example.

Comment: Thanks for answering, if what you mean is that I can only test with head (a few samples), how can I use the built model to classify rest data?  Thanks

Comment: What I was attempting to prompt you to do was to post sufficient information that we could help. Just posting an error message with no data is almost never enough. You need to either do the testing yourself or provide an example to support further investigation.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Run this:

```
trace("create_matrix",edit=T)
```

In the source code box that pops up, line 42 will have a misspelling of the word "acronym".  Change the "A" to an "a" and hit "Save" - it should work fine after that.

Comment: @Chris install the version from [github](https://github.com/timjurka/RTextTools/blob/master/RTextTools/R/create_matrix.R#L31).