# “RTextTools” - fix error in create_matrix on Linux Ubuntu

Tags: r, linux, error-handling

The package "RTextTools" has a known error in the funtion `create_matrix()`. The following post shows how to solve the problem for a single R-Session with the following
[Fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32513513/rtexttools-create-matrix-got-an-error). However, the post only says how to fix the error via `trace("create_matrix",edit=T)`

I run R on a linux server via command line. I am wondering how to fix this problem in such a setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fixed in the latest version on github according to that post.  Download the RTextTools folder from github.  Then do:

```
R CMD BUILD RTextTools
R CMD INSTALL RTextTools_X.X.X.tar.gz
```

Where X.X.X is the version number.

Comment: I figured that out yesterday evening as well. I think you have to uninstall the old RTextTools first and then reinstall the package manually as you decribed above. Maybe you can add that to your answer.  
  
One additional comment, though: The tar.gz provided on github is not the latest version and does not contain the fixed create_matrix() file. You have to download the RTextTools folder and package it to get the latest version.

Comment: The BUILD command is to build to the package from source.  I haven't needed to uninstall a package to install a newer version before, but maybe there's something particular about this one.